# How to add na based on condition for a whole dataframe

Tags: r

I just want to know how to find and replace empty columns into na for a whole data frame

sample data

```
structure(list(id = structure(8.44425875736171e-318, class = "integer64"), 
    project_id = 11L, experiment_id = 85L, 
    gene = "", si = -0.381, pi = "" 
    on1 = "CC", 
    on2 = "GG", 
    on3 = "aa", 
    created_at = structure(1618862091.85075, class = c("POSIXct", 
    "POSIXt"), tzone = "UTC")), row.names = c(NA, -1L), class = c("data.table", 
"data.frame"), .internal.selfref = <pointer: 0x000001ba09da3590>)
```

i have a solution to check for a particular column but i dont how to apply this for whole dataframe

```
data$gene <- ifelse((is.na(data$gene) == TRUE),'NA',data$gene)
```

Comment: Your code for creating your data.frame doesn't work. Also it is quite fuzzy what you would like to do. In your example, it seems that you want to replace NA values with 'NA' string values?

Comment: your gene data is `""` . The following is close to what you tried: `data$gene <- ifelse(data$gene == "", 'NA', data$gene)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use `lapply` with `gsub` to replace each empty cell with NA like this:

```r
df <- structure(list(id = structure(8.44425875736171e-318, class = "integer64"), 
                     project_id = 11L, experiment_id = 85L, 
                     gene = "", si = -0.381, pi = "", 
                     on1 = "CC", 
                     on2 = "GG", 
                     on3 = "aa", 
                     created_at = structure(1618862091.85075, class = c("POSIXct", 
                                                                        "POSIXt"), tzone = "UTC")), row.names = c(NA, -1L), class = c("data.table", 
                                                                                                                                      "data.frame"))

df
#>              id project_id experiment_id gene     si pi on1 on2 on3
#> 1 8.444259e-318         11            85      -0.381     CC  GG  aa
#>            created_at
#> 1 2021-04-19 19:54:51
df[] <- lapply(df, function(x) gsub("^$", NA, x))
df
#>                      id project_id experiment_id gene     si   pi on1 on2 on3
#> 1 8.44425875736171e-318         11            85 <NA> -0.381 <NA>  CC  GG  aa
#>            created_at
#> 1 2021-04-19 19:54:51
```

<sup>Created on 2022-11-02 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Answer (score 2):

You can also use `dplyr` with `mutate` and `across`

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df <- structure(list(id = structure(8.44425875736171e-318, class = "integer64"), 
                     project_id = 11L, experiment_id = 85L, 
                     gene = "", si = -0.381, pi = "", 
                     on1 = "CC", 
                     on2 = "GG", 
                     on3 = "aa", 
                     created_at = structure(1618862091.85075, class = c("POSIXct", 
                                                                        "POSIXt"), tzone = "UTC")), row.names = c(NA, -1L), class = c("data.table", 
                                                                                                                                      "data.frame"))

df %>% 
  mutate(dplyr::across(where(is.character), ~ gsub("^$", NA, .x)))
```

Note that I also attempted to use `replace_na`, however this only works on values that are **actually** `NA`.

```
test %>% 
  mutate(dplyr::across(where(is.character), ~ replace_na(.x, "NA")))
```

- `""` is not considered
- `NA` is considered NA

Keep that in mind while you are performing your analysis.

Answer (score 1):

Using `na_if`

```
library(data.table)
library(dplyr)
df[, lapply(.SD, \(x) if(is.character(x)) na_if(x, "") else x)]
```

-output

```
        id project_id experiment_id   gene     si     pi    on1    on2    on3          created_at
     <i64>      <int>         <int> <char>  <num> <char> <char> <char> <char>              <POSc>
1: 1709137         11            85   <NA> -0.381   <NA>     CC     GG     aa 2021-04-19 19:54:51
```